# Azure Functions App works with direct input url which under "Function App", but doesn't work with url under "Function", neither work with Code + Test

Tags: python, azure, api, azure-functions

I am trying to extract data from Azure SQL with Azure Function.
I created a function with Python code using flask to fetch the data from database.
I have three routes to request:
@app.route('/')
def root():
return 'root'

```
@app.route("/datatable", methods=['GET'])
def get_table():
    out = ''
    query = ''
    try:
        print("")
        query = 'SELECT * from curve'

        db = get_db()
        cursor = db.execute(query)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        columns = cursor.description

        for row in rows:
            out = out + str(row) + "\n"

        out = str(columns) + " " + out
    except Exception as e:
        return logger.error(e)
    
    return out

@app.route("/forwardratetest", methods=['GET'])
def get_forward_rate_test():
    try:

        query = "SELECT rate from curve WHERE [valuationDate] = '1/31/2019' AND  [resetDate] = '12/30/2021' AND [t] ='3'"

        db = get_db()
        cursor = db.execute(query)
        row = cursor.fetchone()

        if row is None:
            rate = 'No Rate Found!'
        else:
            rate = str(row[0])

        return rate
    
    except Exception as e:
        return logger.error(e)
```

After deploy the function from local VS code to cloud, on the Function App page if my App, I can get a url, and run the url successfully.

1. The url on the **Function App page** is:
   https://apitesting.azurewebsites.net
   [image]

with this url, I can get “root”.

2. And under the **Function > Overview > Get Function url** is:
   [https://apitesting.azurewebsites.net//{*route}](https://apitesting.azurewebsites.net//%7B*route%7D)
   [image]
3. But once I click into the **Function > Code + Test > Get Function url** is (with the "api" term):
   [https://apitesting.azurewebsites.net/api/{*route}](https://apitesting.azurewebsites.net/api/%7B*route%7D)
   [image]

The outcome:

1. I can get result “root” from https://apitesting.azurewebsites.net, but NOT from https://apitesting.azurewebsites.net/api (The url from Code + Test)
2. I can get result the correct rate from database through input url directly with https://apitesting.azurewebsites.net/forwarddateratetest, and get the whole data from the table through input url directly with https://apitesting.azurewebsites.net/datatable

But NOT with https://apitesting.azurewebsites.net/api/forwarddateratetest or https://apitesting.azurewebsites.net/api/datatable

It will give me the error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

3. And the reason I tried to input url directly is because that, while I tried to run **“Code + Test”**, I can successfully get “root” once I leave para space (as my route setting “/”)
   [image]

but once I input para as “datatable” or “forwardratetest”, I will always get “HTTP response code 500 Internal Server Error”,
[image]
and the information always shows “Succeeded”, and I went to the “Monitor” to take a look, it always shows Success as “Success” and Result Code as “200”
[image]
[image]

I have no idea why directly inputting url can work, but not in "Code + Test"?
And also why I have two different url, one without api the other one with api, and only the one without api would work.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/fastapi-on-azure-functions) sample azure function using fast Api. I have deployed in azure. I can be able to get the same response as you got.

[image]

Function response which contains api url
[image]

After I changed the **`function.json`** file route has `"route": "{/api/*route}"` I can be able to see the results of Api URL.

```json
{
"scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings": [
    {
        "authLevel": "anonymous",
        "type": "httpTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "name": "req",
        "methods": [
            "get",
            "post"
        ],
        // you can modify accordingly
        "route": "{/api/*route}"
        },
        {
            "type": "http",
            "direction": "out",
            "name": "$return"
        }
    ]
}
```

You have to follow the oute order [(MS-Doc)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-order)to process the exact URL.
[image]

Refer the [MS-DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process,functionsv2&pivots=programming-language-python#customize-the-http-endpoint) for some more information about customize http endpoint